Ignite Clustering Fails when upgrading JDK from 11 to 17
I've been working on a fairly simple proof-of-concept (POC) project using Apache Ignite (started under v2.8, now v2.16.0). Using Java 11, I have 3 simple "server" ignite processes running inside Java processes. I bring up all these processes on the same machine:

Process A: Takes external input, uses a service from Process B, passes data to Process B.
Process B: Publishes a service (used by Process A), some data processing, passes data on to Process C.
Process C: takes the data from Process B, does some processing, can call a service published by Process A.

My POC works under Java 11, but as the future is always moving forward, I wanted to upgrade to Java 17. So I upgraded from:
zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64
to
zulu17.48.15-ca-jdk17.0.10-win_x64
I've consulted the following already regarding using Ignite with Java 11+
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java#running-ignite-with-java-11-or-later
I added the JVM arguments to each of the processes (the numerous --add-opens).  After specifying the new JDK and adding the documented JVM parameters, each process starts up as expected.
HOWEVER, the issue is that each process no longer "clusters" under Java 17. Process A cannot find the service published by Process B. Process A says it is in a cluster by itself, despite Process B and C also running (they are all hard-coded to join same cluster).  I can also change the JDK back to the 11 version, and the clustering functions as expected (even if I leave in the --add-open JVM options in JDK 11).
This seems like a rather fundamental issue... Did I miss something obvious here switching between 11/17 that might explain this behavior? Thanks.
IgniteConfiguration.toString() as requested:
IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=Ignite POC, pubPoolSize=8, svcPoolSize=null, callbackPoolSize=8, stripedPoolSize=8, sysPoolSize=8, mgmtPoolSize=4, dataStreamerPoolSize=8, utilityCachePoolSize=8, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=8, buildIdxPoolSize=2, igniteHome=null, igniteWorkDir=null, mbeanSrv=null, nodeId=null, marsh=null, marshLocJobs=false, p2pEnabled=true, netTimeout=5000, netCompressionLevel=1, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=null, segPlc=USE_FAILURE_HANDLER, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=null, evtSpi=null, colSpi=null, deploySpi=null, indexingSpi=null, addrRslvr=null, encryptionSpi=null, tracingSpi=null, clientMode=false, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=2, rebalanceTimeout=10000, rebalanceBatchesPrefetchCnt=3, rebalanceThrottle=0, rebalanceBatchSize=524288, txCfg=TransactionConfiguration [txSerEnabled=false, dfltIsolation=REPEATABLE_READ, dfltConcurrency=PESSIMISTIC, dfltTxTimeout=0, txTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange=0, pessimisticTxLogSize=0, pessimisticTxLogLinger=10000, tmLookupClsName=null, txManagerFactory=null, useJtaSync=false], cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=10000, sysWorkerBlockedTimeout=null, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=30000, metricsLogFreq=0, connectorCfg=ConnectorConfiguration [jettyPath=null, host=null, port=11211, noDelay=true, directBuf=false, sndBufSize=32768, rcvBufSize=32768, idleQryCurTimeout=600000, idleQryCurCheckFreq=60000, sndQueueLimit=0, selectorCnt=4, idleTimeout=7000, sslEnabled=false, sslClientAuth=false, sslFactory=null, portRange=100, threadPoolSize=8, msgInterceptor=null], odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=1, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=null, binaryCfg=null, memCfg=null, pstCfg=null, dsCfg=null, snapshotPath=snapshots, snapshotThreadPoolSize=4, activeOnStart=true, activeOnStartPropSetFlag=false, autoActivation=true, autoActivationPropSetFlag=false, clusterStateOnStart=null, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=0, sockRcvBufSize=0, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=8, selectorCnt=4, idleTimeout=0, handshakeTimeout=10000, jdbcEnabled=true, odbcEnabled=true, thinCliEnabled=true, sslEnabled=false, useIgniteSslCtxFactory=true, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, thinCliCfg=ThinClientConfiguration [maxActiveTxPerConn=100, maxActiveComputeTasksPerConn=0, sendServerExcStackTraceToClient=false], sesOutboundMsgQueueLimit=0], mvccVacuumThreadCnt=2, mvccVacuumFreq=5000, authEnabled=false, failureHnd=null, commFailureRslvr=null, sqlCfg=SqlConfiguration [longQryWarnTimeout=3000, dfltQryTimeout=0, sqlQryHistSize=1000, validationEnabled=false], asyncContinuationExecutor=null]


Please share your cluster configuration. Ignite 2.16 absolutely works with Java 17.

@StephenDarlington I've added the toString() value of the IgniteConfiguration. The object is just created via Java code, I'm only calling a handful of setters (PeerClassLoadingEnabled(true), MetricsLogFrequency(0), GridLogger(...), setClientMode(false)).
I am able to reproduce the issue simply by swapping between the two JDKs I have listed above. In Java11, clustering works. In Java17, it breaks. No clue why.

What do the logs say? Do the nodes briefly show more server nodes? If you increase the logging level is there any more information?

No node info...  I have a handful of warnings regarding:  peerClassLoading (to disable it for production), -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, message queue size, TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder has no pre-configured addresses, character encoding. Looks like JVM options mostly. I'll try to see if I can make all the warnings disappear, but this feels like grasping at straws.

@StephenDarlington Eliminated all warnings in the Ignite logs, looks like the culprit was needing to set the -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true JVM option. At least it works now under Java 17 with this option.

Looks like the culprit was needing to set the -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true JVM option. This option didn't seem to be needed under Java 11, seems to be needed under Java 17. Go figure...
